# Call function with defaulted parameters through function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I want to write a function template `run` that calls a passed callable which takes no parameters and prints its return value if it is not `void`. Here is my attempt:

```
template<typename FUNC>
void run(FUNC &&f)
{
  if constexpr (std::is_void_v<decltype(f())>)
    f();
  else
    std::cout << f() << std::endl;
}
```

Now here is the problem: I would like `run` to accept functions that do take parameters which all have a default value, i.e.:

```
int foo()
{ return 0; }

int bar(int a = 1, int b = 2)
{ return a + b; }

template<typename FUNC>
void run(FUNC &&f)
{
  if constexpr (std::is_void_v<decltype(f())>)
    f();
  else
    std::cout << f() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  run(foo);
  run(bar); // compiler error, too few arguments to f()
}
```

This does not work yet since default parameters are not part of a functions signature and so I can't call `f()` inside `run`. How can I fix this?

Comment: `run([](){bar();});`?

Comment: @Jarod42 That does not work in general since I would have to treat `void` functions and functions returning something differently (the latter need a `return` inside the lambda).

Comment: I spoke too soon, apparently returning the result of `void` functions from a lambda is fine.

Comment: should be `run([](){ return bar(); });`?